# Tableau Subcategory percentage calculation

Tags: tableau-api, visualization, dashboard, percentage

I have a dataset on demography of the people and their claim amount. In the attached image, i am trying to calculate percentage difference between old and new claim for a particular car type (here, minivan) and two different 'car use' type. You can see the formula i have used to calculate in the screen shot but this formula is not giving correct answer (seems like its calculating for whole dataset).

How should i write the formula to get percentage difference between old and new claims for particular car type and car use? [Tableau Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYBnv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't opened the expression editor, so we're unable to see the calculation you are using here, though looking at your layout, the expression you need is:

```
(Avg(Clm Amt) - Avg(Oldclaim)) / Avg(Oldclaim)
```

Steve